# Exception Type: AssertionError Exception Value: Class RatingSerializers missing "Meta.model" attribute

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

hi guys i a newbie and learning django-framework and building rest-api
i'm stuck at this error . Its gives me error at venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py in get_fields, line 1020. and says Class RatingSerializers missing "Meta.model" attribute.

i did all migration and makemigration

```
    Exception Type: AssertionError
    Exception Value:    
    Class RatingSerializers missing "Meta.model" attribute
```

urls.py

```
    from django.contrib import admin
    from django.urls import path
    from rest_framework import routers
    from django.conf.urls import include
    from .views import MovieViewSet, RatingViewSet

    router = routers.DefaultRouter()
    router.register('movies', MovieViewSet)
    router.register('ratings', RatingViewSet)

    urlpatterns = [
        path('', include(router.urls)),
    ]
```

models.py

```
    from django.db import models
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
    from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator, MinValueValidator
    
    
    class Movie(models.Model):
        title = models.CharField(max_length=32)
        description = models.TextField(max_length=500)


    class Rating(models.Model):
        movie = models.ForeignKey(Movie, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        stars = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1), MaxValueValidator(5)])

        class Meta:
            unique_together = (('user', 'movie'),)
            index_together = (('user', 'movie'),)
```

serializer.py

```
           from rest_framework import serializers
           from .models import Movie, Rating
   
   
           class MovieSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
               class Meta:
                   model: Movie
                   fields = ('id', 'title', 'description')
   
   
           class RatingSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
               class Meta:
                   model: Rating
                   fields = ('id', 'stars', 'user', 'movie')
    views.py
    from django.shortcuts import render
    from rest_framework import viewsets
    from .models import Movie, Rating
    from .serializers import MovieSerializers, RatingSerializers


    class MovieViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
        queryset = Movie.objects.all()
        serializer_class = MovieSerializers


    class RatingViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
        queryset = Rating.objects.all()
        serializer_class = RatingSerializers
```

i have no idea what is wrong with it.

Comment: Could you post the error message?

Answer (score 3):

You have to do

```
model = Rating
```

instead of

```
model: Rating
```

And same for the movies serializer too